# Upload files in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, upload, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am trying to upload image file and bind it with Profile entity. I'm going through the cookbook: there upload handled manualy, but I use FOSUserBundle and process of creating User and Profile is automatic. How can I bind image to Profile? Where do I need to store my pictures?

Comment: I just need to use LifecycleCallbacks) [LifecycleCallbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-lifecycle-callbacks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to override **User Class** of FOSUserBundle and in the overrided **User Class** you will have to include your image filed as described in [How to Handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) .